# MS SSAS Tabular model, unable to switch to DirectQuery mode

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have designed a model with 5 tables. During my first design, my tabular model was in in-memory mode. While I'm designing, I want the model to use direct query mode.

For some reason, I cannot change to direct query mode using Visual Studio. When I change to direct query mode "On", the model seems to be processed, but the result is that nothing is changed.

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Jacco